# Find Duplicated data in multiple cells and copy all to other excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

I have excel sheet with around 40k records and 5 columns. I want to search duplicates in column 3, 4, 5 and copy whole row in new sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Emm Jay could you please be more specific? I m not sure what are you asking for, but the below code may help you to get an overall idea.

Let's say that Sheet 1 contains our data & duplicate rows will copy on Sheet 2.

Sheet 1:

[image]

Sheet 2 - Output:

[image]

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Duplicates()

    Dim LastrowS1 As Long, LastrowS2 As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim CombineStrI As String, CombineStrJ As String

    LastrowS1 = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastrowS1

        CombineStrI = Sheet1.Range("C" & i).Value & "_" & Sheet1.Range("D" & i).Value & "_" & Sheet1.Range("E" & i).Value

        For j = 2 To LastrowS1

            CombineStrJ = Sheet1.Range("C" & j).Value & "_" & Sheet1.Range("D" & j).Value & "_" & Sheet1.Range("E" & j).Value

            If j <> i Then

                If CombineStrI = CombineStrJ Then
                    Sheet1.Rows(i).Copy
                    LastrowS2 = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    Sheet2.Range("A" & LastrowS2 + 1).PasteSpecial
                End If

            End If

        Next j

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but what I want is in Sheet1 there are 5 columns and I want to check column C, D and E at same time for duplication if found then copy both duplicated rows to Sheet2

Comment: So, what are asking for is combine Col 3 value & Col 4 value & Col 5 value together as one string and check for duplicates?

Comment: the excel went on not responding even waiting for about 30 minutes

Comment: I tried to run on 1000 records and it works fine. Thanks for your solution